# Is it possible that changing the structure of website URLs has affected how the page appears to search engines and social media sites?

Tags: php, html, facebook-share

I changed my website URL structure recently from https://test.com/abc/1 to https://test.com/abc/xyz. And after that, I tried to share it on facebook but the preview is showing website blurb. I check it with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ and preview is correct, but there is a warning `Missing Properties The following required properties are missing: og:url, fb:app_id` other than that `og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, og:updated_time, og:image:alt` are correct.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Yes it will change how it appears. Wordpress tells you this when you're chaning it in permalinks section. In . regards to missing tags, install yoast seo plugin

Comment: @SimoneRossaini HTML header?

Comment: @GBWDev I'm not using PHP not Wordpress

Comment: oh ok, well then the first part of my comment still applies. For the missing tags.. you simply just need to add them?

Comment: I don't understand, you use pure PHP or Wordpress?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'm using pure PHP

Comment: @Lucky13 have you tried to write the missing tag?